# "SQLiteDiskIOException: error code 10: disk I/O error" retuns on ICS and Samsung Nexus on DROP TABLE

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm getting the following error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: error code 10: disk I/O error
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:92)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1926)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1866)
```

I only get this error on ICS 4.0.1 on a Samsung Nexus phone. On an emulator, a Motorola Xoom 3.2 and an HTC Desire 2.3.3, the code works fine. My code is targeted at version 8, or 2.2.x, of the SDK. The `execSQL` is executed as follows:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table.getTableName());
```

The database is stored internally and not on an SD card. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Solved this.

Problem was that prior to the drop table statements there was a `Context.deleteDatabase('dbName')` statement which had obviously removed the db, and the I/O error being reported then makes perfect sense.

It seems that a belt and braces approach had been used previously (unnecessarily).

However the interesting thing is that this didn't manifest as a problem until the move to ICS.

Comment: Ran into the same error. Thanks for the answer. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem, when encrypted database was not able to properly drop table with ForeignKey/Index. Deleting existing records just before dropping table resolved issue:

```
fun SupportSQLiteDatabase.dropTable(name: String) {
    execSQL("DELETE FROM $name")
    execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $name")
}
```